# Issues installing Anaconda2 on Linux

Tags: python, linux

I get this error trying to install anaconda2,I tried both the x64 and x86 installer,any suggestions?

```
        installing: _cache-0.0-py27_x0 ...
        installing: python-2.7.11-0 ...
        installing: alabaster-0.7.7-py27_0 ...
        installing: anaconda-client-1.4.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: anaconda-navigator-1.1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: argcomplete-1.0.0-py27_1 ...
        installing: astropy-1.1.2-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: babel-2.2.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: backports_abc-0.4-py27_0 ...
        installing: beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: bitarray-0.8.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: blaze-0.9.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: bokeh-0.11.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: boto-2.39.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: bottleneck-1.0.0-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: cairo-1.12.18-6 ...
        installing: cdecimal-2.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: cffi-1.5.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: chest-0.2.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: cloudpickle-0.1.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: clyent-1.2.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: colorama-0.3.7-py27_0 ...
        installing: conda-manager-0.3.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: configobj-5.0.6-py27_0 ...
        installing: cryptography-1.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: curl-7.45.0-0 ...
        installing: cycler-0.10.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: cython-0.23.4-py27_0 ...
        installing: cytoolz-0.7.5-py27_0 ...
        installing: dask-0.8.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: datashape-0.5.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: decorator-4.0.9-py27_0 ...
        installing: dill-0.2.4-py27_0 ...
        tinstalling: docutils-0.12-py27_0 ...
        installing: dynd-python-0.7.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: enum34-1.1.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: fastcache-1.0.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: flask-0.10.1-py27_1 ...
        installing: flask-cors-2.1.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: fontconfig-2.11.1-5 ...
        installing: freetype-2.5.5-0 ...
        installing: funcsigs-0.4-py27_0 ...
        installing: futures-3.0.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: gevent-1.1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: greenlet-0.4.9-py27_0 ...
        installing: grin-1.2.1-py27_1 ...
        installing: h5py-2.5.0-np110py27_4 ...
        installing: hdf5-1.8.15.1-2 ...
        installing: heapdict-1.0.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: idna-2.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: ipaddress-1.0.14-py27_0 ...
        installing: ipykernel-4.3.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: ipython-4.1.2-py27_1 ...
        installing: ipython_genutils-0.1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: ipywidgets-4.1.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: itsdangerous-0.24-py27_0 ...
        installing: jbig-2.1-0 ...
        installing: jdcal-1.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: jedi-0.9.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: jinja2-2.8-py27_0 ...
        installing: jpeg-8d-0 ...
        installing: jsonschema-2.4.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: jupyter-1.0.0-py27_2 ...
        installing: jupyter_client-4.2.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: jupyter_console-4.1.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: jupyter_core-4.1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: libdynd-0.7.2-0 ...
        installing: libffi-3.0.13-0 ...
        installing: libgfortran-3.0-0 ...
        installing: libpng-1.6.17-0 ...
        installing: libsodium-1.0.3-0 ...
        installing: libtiff-4.0.6-1 ...
        installing: libxml2-2.9.2-0 ...
        installing: libxslt-1.1.28-0 ...
        installing: llvmlite-0.9.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: locket-0.2.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: lxml-3.6.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: markupsafe-0.23-py27_0 ...
        installing: matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: mistune-0.7.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: mkl-11.3.1-0 ...
        installing: mkl-service-1.1.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: mpmath-0.19-py27_0 ...
        installing: multipledispatch-0.4.8-py27_0 ...
        installing: nbconvert-4.1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: nbformat-4.0.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: networkx-1.11-py27_0 ...
        installing: nltk-3.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: nose-1.3.7-py27_0 ...
        installing: notebook-4.1.0-py27_1 ...
        installing: numba-0.24.0-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: numexpr-2.5-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: numpy-1.10.4-py27_1 ...
        installing: odo-0.4.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: openpyxl-2.3.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: openssl-1.0.2g-0 ...
        installing: pandas-0.18.0-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: partd-0.3.2-py27_1 ...
        installing: patchelf-0.8-0 ...
        installing: path.py-8.1.2-py27_1 ...
        installing: patsy-0.4.0-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: pep8-1.7.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: pexpect-4.0.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: pickleshare-0.5-py27_0 ...
        installing: pillow-3.1.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: pip-8.1.1-py27_1 ...
        installing: pixman-0.32.6-0 ...
        installing: ply-3.8-py27_0 ...
        installing: psutil-4.1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: ptyprocess-0.5-py27_0 ...
        installing: py-1.4.31-py27_0 ...
        installing: pyasn1-0.1.9-py27_0 ...
        installing: pycairo-1.10.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: pycosat-0.6.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: pycparser-2.14-py27_0 ...
        installing: pycrypto-2.6.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: pycurl-7.19.5.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: pyflakes-1.1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: pygments-2.1.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: pyopenssl-0.15.1-py27_2 ...
        installing: pyparsing-2.0.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: pyqt-4.11.4-py27_1 ...
        installing: pytables-3.2.2-np110py27_1 ...
        installing: pytest-2.8.5-py27_0 ...
        installing: python-dateutil-2.5.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: pytz-2016.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: pyyaml-3.11-py27_1 ...
        installing: pyzmq-15.2.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: qt-4.8.7-1 ...
        installing: qtawesome-0.3.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: qtconsole-4.2.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: qtpy-1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: readline-6.2-2 ...
        installing: redis-2.6.9-0 ...
        installing: redis-py-2.10.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: requests-2.9.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: rope-0.9.4-py27_1 ...
        installing: scikit-image-0.12.3-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: scikit-learn-0.17.1-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: scipy-0.17.0-np110py27_2 ...
        installing: setuptools-20.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: simplegeneric-0.8.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: sip-4.16.9-py27_0 ...
        installing: six-1.10.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: snowballstemmer-1.2.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: sockjs-tornado-1.0.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: sphinx-1.3.5-py27_0 ...
        installing: sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.9-py27_0 ...
        installing: spyder-2.3.8-py27_1 ...
        installing: sqlalchemy-1.0.12-py27_0 ...
        installing: sqlite-3.9.2-0 ...
        installing: ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py27_0 ...
        installing: statsmodels-0.6.1-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: sympy-1.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: terminado-0.5-py27_1 ...
        installing: tk-8.5.18-0 ...
        installing: toolz-0.7.4-py27_0 ...
        installing: tornado-4.3-py27_0 ...
        installing: traitlets-4.2.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: unicodecsv-0.14.1-py27_0 ...
        installing: util-linux-2.21-0 ...
        installing: werkzeug-0.11.4-py27_0 ...
        installing: wheel-0.29.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: xlrd-0.9.4-py27_0 ...
        installing: xlsxwriter-0.8.4-py27_0 ...
        installing: xlwt-1.0.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: xz-5.0.5-1 ...
        installing: yaml-0.1.6-0 ...
        installing: zeromq-4.1.3-0 ...
        installing: zlib-1.2.8-0 ...
        installing: anaconda-4.0.0-np110py27_0 ...
        installing: conda-4.0.5-py27_0 ...
        installing: conda-build-1.20.0-py27_0 ...
        installing: conda-env-2.4.5-py27_0 ...
        python2.7: Cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ./Anaconda2-4.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 461: 23325 Killed                  $PYTHON -E -V
        ERROR:
        cannot execute native linux-64 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
        SunOS gaffer 5.10 Generic_142901-13 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no Anaconda installer to SunOS. Anaconda support only Windows, Linux and MacOS. Please verify link: https://www.continuum.io/downloads